# Mystery - XDomainRequest sometimes works and sometimes not

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, cross-domain

This is a mystery, the following code sometimes works and sometimes not in IE8, and the server is always online!

```
var r = new XDomainRequest();
r.open("GET", link);
r.send();
r.onload = function(){
    alert(r.responseText);
}
```

Sometimes it's alert the response of server, sometimes nothing! How to solve it with pure javascript?

Comment: If onload isn't firing, then onerror is.  You'll need to handle that as well.

Comment: @RayNicholus but with xmlhttprequest() it's works every time, why?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest and XDomainRequest are different in many ways.  The request could fail for any number of reasons.

Comment: Also, you should be setting onload BEFORE you open and send the request.  Not after.

Comment: @RayNicholus thanks you a lot mate, I solved with your tip.